# android connection bluetooth auto

Tags: android, bluetooth

I found some good tuto on google to create an application with bluetooth, but I found nothing to connect the bluetooth and manage automaticaly any devise by the system (like keyboard, mouse, headphone).

(I dont want to create a new use of bluetooth, but only manage connexions).

Do you have any idea to do this ?

Thanks for your answers,
Alex

Comment: Hi hi hi,
no one have any idea ?

I can't go ahead... So, thanks to every one who could help me a bit !

Comment: Always nobody...
is that impossible ??